# Postgresql in Node-red

Tags: postgresql, http, server, client, node-red

I use node-red to create an Api from a server. I want to read and send data via http. I use the browser-based programming method. I want to send data from a postgresql database. I installed the package node-red-contrib-postgres-multi. I don´t know how to put data into the database and how to read data from the database, because I cannot find examples.

Does anybody knows, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `postgrestor` [postgrestor package](https://flows.nodered.org/node/postgrestor) where you can define query or data modification statement directly in node window. It also allows parametrized queries via template engine.

The problem I've encountered is working with more than one db instance in the same flow but if you need only one db instance connection it should work for you.